# Typescript inferred generic type is unknown in conditional type

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, typescript-generics, inference

I can't wrap my head around why the `data` property isn't properly inferred to `FeatureFlagData` in the arguments to `createRoute`. Essentially what I am trying to achieve is infer the type of `data` in the `createRoute` argument, based on the item in `canActivate` array (as it implements the generic `GuardWithData`). What am I missing here? Also, is there a better way of achieving the same thing?

Here is some example code:

```
interface Guard {
    canActivate: () => boolean
}

export interface GuardWithData<D> extends Guard {
  data?: D;
}

export type DataType<T> = T extends GuardWithData<infer D> ? D : unknown;

class FeatureFlagGuard implements GuardWithData<FeatureFlagData> {
    canActivate() { return true; };
}

interface Route {
    canActivate: any,
    data?: object
}

interface FeatureFlagData {
    featureFlag: string;
}

type ExtractGuardData<A extends Route> = A extends {
    canActivate: GuardWithData<infer U>,
}
  ? Route & { data: U }
    : never;

function createRoute<U extends Route>(route: ExtractGuardData<U>) {
  return route;
}

createRoute({
    canActivate: FeatureFlagGuard,
    data: {} // <-- This type is to unknown, rather than the expected FeatureFlagData
})
```

Comment: I'm not following the logic of why you expect `data` to be inferred to be of type `FeatureFlagData`. Could you explain why you expect it to be like that?

Comment: My hope was that when I invoke `createRoute`, Typescript would be able to infer `U` in `ExtractGuardData` and in turn also infer the generic type in `GuardWithData` that I would later be able to use to create the compositional type (or intersection type) `Route & { data: U }` (in `ExtractGuardData`) where type `U` is inferred to be the same as `D` in `GuardWithData` (aka `FeatureFlagData`). I suspect I am doing something fundamentally wrong here (or at the very least have the wrong expectations) but I can't figure out what or how to get the behaviour that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Guard {
    canActivate: () => boolean
}
```

This means an object with the property `canActivate` that is a boolean function. The way you're passing in `FeatureFlagGuard` to `createRoute`, it looks like you want `FeatureFlagGuard` to be the boolean function, not an object with the `canActivate` property.

```
interface Guard {
  (): boolean
}

export interface GuardWithData<D> extends Guard {
  (data?: D): boolean;
}

const FeatureFlagGuard: GuardWithData<FeatureFlagData> =
  (data?: FeatureFlagData) => true;

interface Route<D> {
  canActivate: GuardWithData<D>,
  data?: D
}

interface FeatureFlagData {
  featureFlag: string;
}

function createRoute<D>(route: Route<D>) {
  return route;
}

createRoute({
  canActivate: FeatureFlagGuard,
  data: {}
})
```

Comment: Right I probably wasn't too clear that `canActivate` in `Route` is merely a naming convention that happens to have the same name as the require method `canActivate` in the `Guard` interface.

Comment: I have to adhere to the `Guard` interface but still be able to dictate the type of the `data` property in the `createRoute` args by just having my `Guard` extend a given `GuardWithData<FeatureFlagData>`. So the underlying framework (Angular in this case) expects that `canActivate` property in `createRoute` is of type `Guard` (which is defined as in my initial question). Therefore the only parts that I can control/modify is `GuardWithData` , `FeatureFlagGuard`, `ExtractGuardData` and `FeatureFlagData` is that makes sense?